# How to insert multiple images in ms word and fits in one page separately?

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I want to insert my scanned 10  a4 size images at once so that each image occupy one page each.
Any shortcut keys available to make each image come at new page separately?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Select all pictures at once and insert Word, if the image size is A4, you can set the paper size to A4 before insert pictures.

Comment: Huh... that's not my question. I want each pictures to occupy one page separately. That's it. One picture per page.